# Adding DropDownLists to a user control C#

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I have never used user controls in C# .NET, and am working on a project where I have 3 dropdownlists, and need to put them into a user control. I was wondering how I would go about doing this. I will post the  code for my dropdownlists, and a screen grab of what they currently look like, and what they should look like. Thanks.

```
 public partial class _default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
                DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
                DropDownList3.DataBind();
            }
        }

        // Drop Down List 1
        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDataSource2.XPath = String.Format("mmsdata/mill[@n='{0}']/mach", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        }
        // Drop Down List 2
        protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDataSource3.XPath = String.Format("mmsdata/mill[@n='{0}']/mach[@n='{1}']/srn", DropDownList1.SelectedValue, DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            BindSensorList();
        }

        protected void BindSensorList()
        {
            //sender.GetType();
            XmlDocument xdoc = XmlDataSource3.GetXmlDocument();
            XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes(XmlDataSource3.XPath);
            var sensors = new List<Sensor>();
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                sensors.Add(new Sensor { id = node.Attributes["n"].Value, name = node.InnerText });
            }

            DropDownList3.DataSource = sensors;
            DropDownList3.DataValueField = "id";
            DropDownList3.DataTextField = "name";
            DropDownList3.DataBind();
        }
```

What I want them to look like

[image: First picture]

What they look like

[image: Second Picture]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add your dropdown to the user control is to create a user control in the project solution, and then put the asp.net webform code in the ui and you can then write a code behind for it same way you create a web forms.

**Sample User Control**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="SampleUserControl" %>
<h3> <u>User Control</u> </h3>
<script runat=server>
</script>
Drop down 1:    <asp:DropDownList id="ColorList"
                AutoPostBack="True"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change"
                runat="server">

              <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="Silver"> Silver </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="DarkGray"> Dark Gray </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="Khaki"> Khaki </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="DarkKhaki"> Dark Khaki </asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:label id="Label1" runat=server/>
```

You can use a user control on a page and dynamically load its content, just initialise it on the page you wish to use it on and pass in values the same way you load a class/page

Comment: "What they look Like" and "What I want them to look like" were backwards, I need them to be the opposite, I fixed the comment on the pictures. It is correct now

Comment: @JordanDarland isnt that just a styling issue ?, if you apply classes  or IDs to your dropdown controls when you dynamically created them, you can style them however you want in css.